# start playing music on spotify from another iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, spotify

iv created an app but id like to add a feature where when i press a button it opens my spotify app and automatically plays music... if this is even possible that is... iv got most of it done i think, iv got the button and it opens spotify but cant find out how to auto play, has anyone done this or knows how to?

```
-(IBAction)spotify:(id)sender {

NSString *stringURL = @"spotify:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

please help :)

Comment: iOS sandboxing mechanism makes it impossible for one app to access another. So I don't think you can do more things after launching another app.

Comment: I think this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111848/opening-spotify-app-from-my-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

You can open most `spotify:` URLs (using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:];`) and the Spotify iOS client will open and show them.

There's some documentation [here](http://www.spotify.com/us/blog/archives/2008/01/14/linking-to-spotify/) - make sure you use `spotify:` URIs and not HTTP URLs.

However, the iOS client currently doesn't support autoplay that I'm aware of - it'll be up to the user to push play.

Alternatively, you could use CocoaLibSpotify to embed Spotify playback right inside your app.